# issue with rails s & also bundle install giving "could not find compatible versions for gem" - new to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I downloaded and installed railsinstaller and was doing fine.  However, I am now having some issues when I tried to do `rails s`

This is what I see:

```
Could not find gem 'haml (~> 4.0.6) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine.
```

It says, "Run bundle install to install missing gems"

So when I do `bundle install` here is what I see:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass":
  In Gemfile:
    bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3.5.1) x86-mingw32 depends on
      sass (>= 3.3.0) x86-mingw32

    sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) x86-mingw32 depends on
      sass (3.2.0)
```

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.6'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.0'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bootstrap-sass README](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/README.md) recommends this Gemfile configuration:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
```

Have you tried that instead of specifying `~> 4.0.3` for sass-rails?

Comment: Thank you.  No I did not try that, but I did after you mention it and it is working fine now.